# uiscrollview lagging with gradient cell background

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi guys since I have an UITableView with a custom cell where I parse some XML data, to make the cell stylish I used this code for gradient background, now the problem is that my app lags once I scroll down or up in the tableview.
This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"ProvidersCell";
ProvidersViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ProvidersViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];       
}
NSString*imageurl = [XMLReader getValue:[[providers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Image"]];
if ([imageurl  isEqual: @""]) {
    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www./nopic.jpg"]]];

    cell.provider_img.image=myImage;
}else{
    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]]];

    cell.provider_img.image=myImage;
}
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    grad.frame = cell.bounds;
    grad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0 green:241/255.0 blue:242/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:231/255.0 green:231/255.0 blue:232/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:207/255.0 blue:207/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

    [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer *selectedGrad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    selectedGrad.frame = cell.bounds;
    selectedGrad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:24/255.0 green:215/255.0 blue:229/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:22/255.0 green:206/255.0 blue:219/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:9/255.0 green:173/255.0 blue:185/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedGrad atIndex:0];


cell.provider_name.text =[XMLReader getValue:[[providers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Name"]];
cell.provider_condition.text = [XMLReader getValue:[[providers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Condition"]];
cell.provider_payout.text = [XMLReader getValue:[[providers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Payout"]];
NSString*rating = [XMLReader getValue:[[providers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Rating"]];
NSInteger rate = [rating integerValue];

return cell;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems on your code:

1) You are downloading the image on the main thread, you should do it on other thread. Try to use SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for it;

2) You may want to create your custom cell, you are doing a lot of work on cellForRowAtIndexPath. Try to create your shadow using UIBezierPath and set the yourCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES

Comment: may this 2 problems affect iphone battery dramatically?

Comment: just one more question, when I put the code into if (cell == nil){} my tableview remains empty, instead of creating the cell once for reusability?

Comment: inside if (cell == nil){} you just need to initialize your cell, nothing more